# How to break out of a loop and return a value in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm doing a match statement like this:

```rust
let command: u32 = match command.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => {
        num
    },
    Err(_) => {}
}
```

But this whole thing is in a loop {}

How do I break out of the loop and also return the num?

I've been trying something like this:

```rust
let command: u32 = match command.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => {
        num;
        break 'inner;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't return anything because of the semicolon. And if I switch the break and num, the num is unreachable. So how do I combine these two?

This is the whole code:

```
for n in players {
    println!("It's {}s turn", n.name);

    'inner: loop {
        println!("Input 1 to throw the dice");

        let mut command = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut command)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let command: u32 = match command.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => {
                num;
                break 'inner;
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("You need to input 1 to throw");
                continue 'inner;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does your whole loop look like ?

Comment: @imperosol I added it to the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without that, it wouldn't work, because your println statement return `()` which you cannot assign to `u32`. Even if it succeeded, the lifetime of `command` is limited to the loop so you can't use it after breaking out.

For your particular problem, I think the `break val` syntax can help you :

```
let command: u32 = loop {
    println!("Input 1 to throw the dice");

    let mut command = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut command)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    match command.trim().parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(res) => break res,
        Err(_) => println!("invalid")
    };
};
```